# SSH doesn't ask for my password

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, passwords, coda

I've been logging in to this server through the terminal in coda 2, which has a spot to enter my password in the gui. Unfortunately, it keeps disconnection while sass is watching a file and I have to restart it. I was hoping to just ssh through the OSX terminal and keep it open separate from Coda. I can ssh without a password because it uses a key, but it only logs in to my home folder and I can't access the root(and it says I'm not in sudoers file). Somehow the password is being sent through coda and allowing me adequate access, but I'm not sure how it is sending the password.

How do I force SSH to ask for my password even though it's set to use the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass these options to OpenSSH:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```